# Javascript not running after triggering onclick event

Tags: javascript, html

I want to validate my login form after clicking on "Log In" button and then on success I have to run a php file.But validation script is not running.Below is my snippet.

```
  <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="services.js"></script>
    </head>
<body>
    <form method="post" action="log.php">
    <div id="PasswordField" class="col-xs-4"/>
                    <label for="u_pswd">Password:</label>
                    <input id="u_pswd" type="password" class="form-control" size="25%" placeholder="Enter alteast 8 characters" />
                </div>
                <br><br><br><br>
                <button id="submit" name="checkout" class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" value="submit" onclick="return success()">Log In</button>
    </form>
</body>

//services.js
function logInPass(){
    var pass = document.getElementById("u_pswd");
    var re = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$");

    if(u_pswd=="")
        alert("Please enter password !");
    else
        if(u_pswd.search(" ")!=-1)
            alert("please enter valid password");

    if(!re.test(pass))
        alert("Please enter valid password");
}
```

Comment: Do you see an error in your console? The problem with `return validation_function();` is that an Error in your validation function will cause the return to skip and it will submit anyway. Consider using `addEventListener` and `event.preventDefault();`. Also, the validation check should be moved to the `onsubmit` of the form as there are more ways to submit a form than by clicking a button (pressing `[enter]` for instance).

Comment: Please forgive, human error.

Comment: You're not returning anything from the click handler, hence the submit takes place. Hmm... in the HTML you're calling `success()`, the function in the example is `logInPass`.

Comment: I see an Error in your code. You're using `u_pswd` but this variable is not defined. Also `pass` is not a string but a DOMElement. Add `var u_pswd = pass.value;` to get the value. `re.test(pass)` should then be `re.test(u_pswd)`

Comment: I made some changes: `<form method="post" onsubmit="logInPass()" action="log.php">` and `document.getElementById("u_pswd").value;` but still not working

Comment: @Teemu: I'd removed `onclick` event from submit button and did the above changes but still its not working out

Comment: @Halcyon: The changes you mentioned didn't work out.Also I have no knowledge of eventListener.

Comment: where is success function?

Comment: @user2181397: I removed it. Refer recent comments.

Comment: When all the changes suggested in the comments above are done and the messy variable names fixed, the code works, with [a button click handler](http://jsfiddle.net/z2h7w54k/) or [a form submit handler](http://jsfiddle.net/z2h7w54k/1/) ...

Comment: Thanks everyone but even if the alert message pops up it runs the php file.Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: The linked fiddles don't submit anything after an alert. Notice the curly braces and `return false`s  in the code.

Comment: I missed one return statement...so embarrassing.Again thanks @Teemu.

Answer (score 0):

I tested the following code. will you please check it
Sorry i am new to stack over flow

```
function logInPass(){
     var pass = document.getElementById("u_pswd").value;
     var re = new RegExp("^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[a-z])(?=.*?[0-9])(?=.*?[#?!@$%^&*-]).{8,}$");
if(pass == "")  
{
    alert("Please enter password !");
    return false;
}
else
{
    if(pass.search(" ")!=-1)
    {
        alert("please enter valid password");
        return false;
    }
}

if(!re.test(pass))
{
    alert("Please enter valid password");
    return false;
}
```

}

Please replace onsubmit attribute by this one also onsubmit="return logInPass()"